# patch -p1 < MDVA-43395_EE_2.4.3-p1_v1.composer.patch

Tags: magento2, security-patch

I could successfully follow the instructions to install the latest security patches on our Magento store running on community version 2.4.2. I'm not sure if patches really installed well because I find only a few files modified as the screenshot below shows. Kindly confirm if everything went well with the install.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

waaaait, do You really keep vendor content in Your project Repo?
It is not really a good idea. Vendor catalog should be added to .gtignore.
You should manage packages via files compsoer.json and composer.lock.
Vendor should be installed on Server with `composer install` command. In that case adding patches would be super simple - by adding one or two more lines to Your composer.json

HOWEVER, answering Your question, look like Patches were installed correctly. I mean, at least files related to patches were modified.

Comment: Thanks Konrad for the additional helpful tips on the vendor thing. Yes, we put everything within vendor in the the git repository. I will consider discussing this with my manager to see what he says.

Comment: Could you please share your skype ID?

Comment: Konrad, is it necessary to check in all those untracked files and a directory too? Please let me know what you think.

Comment: hey, I am not using skype.  What do You mean by `to check in` all untracked files? Just changes related to PATCH? It is hard to tell. I dont know right now which files are untracked for Your project. However, Magento Patches should modify only Magento core files - or files from related modules in vendor. Also, You can just open PATCH and verify change files and changes in files. You can also compare it with current status.

Comment: Thanks Konrad. When I say check in, I thought it means checking them into git repository.

Comment: Here You can check default Magento .gitignore file for Magento 2.4 https://raw.githubusercontent.com/magento/magento2/2.4/.gitignore . It means that all mentioned directory should not be added to git. But keep in mind, that change like that may require some adaptations. For example You have to manage ap/etc/env.php file per env - it will should be different for Local, stage , and prod. Also You may want to add to git app/etc/config.php - especially if You have some disabled modules.

Comment: This file app/etc/config.php stays out of .gitignore file. We're tracking addition, deactivation and activation of modules with this config.php.

Comment: Jup but still, the main goal is to move some responsibilities of managing code / packages / modules to composer directly. There is no point in keeping /vendor in project git repo. Especially if You are doing `composer install` on deploy anyway. In that case, the whole /vendor will be overridden. But still -  have no clue how You are managing the project.

Comment: I feel I'm not paying attention to Magento best practices after reading your comments. I should discuss this with my manager. I would like to mention that we are not worried if the /vendor gets overridden each time composer install is run. I think this is not right. Let me hear from him what he thinks. Thanks for sharing the valuable information.

Comment: Yea, in that case applying Patch like You did, and deploy it to Your Project repo, will not have an effect on Production, because vendor will be overridden on prod env. Also, any changes You made locally in vendor and deploy to repo, probably will be overridden on deploy. To quick fix that, please read about https://github.com/magento/quality-patches . You can add Magento/quality-patches to Your project in composer.json. Also You can apply patches in Composer.json. Thanks to that, patches will be always applied ;) There is quite nice introduction how it works

Comment: Thanks for your efforts trying to enlighten me on this. This seems to be too important. Since I didn't work with more than just 1 Magento project in the last one year, I haven't had enough opportunities to look into stuff like the ones you are talking about.